# How to get all the keys of objects in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am wondering what is a better approach to extract all the keys and values of objects in an array as separate arrays. My approach requires me to flatten the array after extracting keys and values of the object by mapping over the array.

> **Input**
>
> const input = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"c": 3}, {"d": 4}, {}, {"e": null, "f": 6, "g": 7}];
>
> **Output**
>
> const keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
>
> const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, null, 6, 7];

**My Solution**

```js
const input = [{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}, {
  "c": 3
}, {
  "d": 4
}, {}, {
  "e": null,
  "f": 6,
  "g": 7
}];
const keys = input.map(obj => [].concat(Object.keys(obj))).flat();
console.log(keys);
const values = input.map(obj => [].concat(Object.values(obj))).flat();
console.log(values);
```

Comment: This would be a question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Aah, thanks for introducing me to this wonderful platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which is what you have implemented

> The flatMap() method first maps each element using a mapping function, then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a map() followed by a flat() of depth 1, but flatMap() is often quite useful, as merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.

```js
const input = [{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}, {
  "c": 3
}, {
  "d": 4
}, {}, {
  "e": null,
  "f": 6,
  "g": 7
}];

const keys = input.flatMap(Object.keys);
const values = input.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(keys,values)
```

Comment: There is no need to create a new callback function. You can just do `flatMap(Object.keys)`... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try one `reduce` function so you don't do two loops, and get it all done in one loop?

```js
const input = [{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}, {
  "c": 3
}, {
  "d": 4
}, {}, {
  "e": null,
  "f": 6,
  "g": 7
}];

const { keys, values } = input.reduce((accum, obj) => ({
  keys: [...accum.keys, ...Object.keys(obj)],
  values: [...accum.values, ...Object.values(obj)],
}), { keys: [], values: [] });

console.log(keys, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get key and then flat an array:

```js
const input = [
  { "a": 1, "b": 2 },
  { "c": 3 }, { "d": 4 },
  {},
  { "e": null, "f": 6, "g": 7 }
];

const keys = input.map(a=> Object.keys(a)).flat();
const values = input.map(a=> Object.values(a)).flat();

console.log(keys)
console.log(values)
```